# Default SSH credentials for CoreOS?

Tags: ssh, coreos, openstack-nova

I am trying to play around with CoreOS, and I just went to their ISO download site and downloaded the latest stable ISO. I then created a new VM instance with that ISO, and it looks like the instance is  up and running beautifully.

I would now like to SSH into this machine, but it just dawned on me that I don't have a username/password. Any ideas as to what the default/root passwords would be?  I checked the CoreOS site and can't seem to find any.

---

**Nitty gritty details**: I actually uploaded the ISO to a local OpenStack cluster, which took care of creating the image for me, but I don't think that matters.

Comment: There is no default password, you need to [provide ssh keys](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/openstack/).

Comment: Another question, rather than using the ISO why didn't you upload the OpenStack OEM to glance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the rep to comment, but Micheal Hampton is correct, CoreOS has a root user and a core user, neither of which have passwords.

If you have the Openstack CLI set up, you can issue `nova keypair-list` to see your keys and `nova keypair-add --pub-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <keyname>` to add a new one. You should then be able to SSH in as the core user, with that key. (Though you may have to cycle the VM - not sure.) Note that this is passed through the openstack metadata service.

As Brian Redbeard points out, you can also put ssh-keys in the cloud-config yaml file. That can be passed through either the metadata service or the cloud drive as the `user-data` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The correct thing to do in this case is to specify the use of an ssh-key through a [cloud-config](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/blob/master/Documentation/cloud-config.md) file.  This can be done via a command line boot argument or with a [config drive](https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-config-drive/).